# javascript how to get json data with api call to redirected url

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, .htaccess, redirect

I'm fetching json data from gltich API.

> https://wind-bow.gomix.me/twitch-api/users/freecodecamp

When I go to that link, the url redirects to another domain

> https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/users/freecodecamp
>
> *(domain name change from `gomix.me` to `glitch.me`)*

Using [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) for both HTTPs request, I get the same JSON data. However, both don't produce the same results when using jQuery `.getJSON` method

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("https://wind-bow.gomix.me/twitch-api/users/freecodecamp", function(data1) {
      console.log("Gomix.me URL", data1); // nothing outputted
    });
    
    $.getJSON("https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/users/freecodecamp", function(data2) {
      console.log("Glitch.me URL", data2); // expected data outputted
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Is it possible to get JSON data through a URL that will be redirected `gomix.me`, or am I only able to use the final endpoint only `glitch.me`?

Answer (score 2):

Gomix request is blocked by CORS policy. You can use this heroku app to bypass it: https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://wind-bow.gomix.me/twitch-api/users/freecodecamp", function(data1) {
      console.log("Gomix.me URL", data1); // now it works
    });
    
    $.getJSON("https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/users/freecodecamp", function(data2) {
      console.log("Glitch.me URL", data2); // expected data outputted
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: could I not specify something like ?callback=? at the end of my https request instead?

Answer (score 1):

If you use `$.ajax` with `dataType: 'jsonp'` it helps you.

```
$(document).ready(function() {         
    $.ajax({
    url: "https://wind-bow.gomix.me/twitch-api/users/freecodecamp",   
    type: 'GET',   
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data1) { console.log("Gomix.me URL", data1);}      
    });   
});
```